# How to use a number attached to a string in associative array

Tags: php, arrays, associative

I have a card deck array:

```
$cards = array("2_of hearts" => 2, "3_of_hearts" => 3, "king_of_hearts" => 10);
```

And I want to echo the name of the card somewhere (example: 2_of_hearts) but also calculate something with the number attached to it, but I really can't seem to make it work. Also, I was unable to find a working answer for me.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Did you consider to create a Card class with face, suit and value? It's much easier to access object properties than to process string to get some values.

Answer (score 1):

If you use a foreach loop that provides you with the key and the value like this, you get both the `2_of hearts` and the `2` as variables.

```
$cards = array("2_of hearts" => 2, "3_of_hearts" => 3, "king_of_hearts" => 10);
foreach ( $cards as $name => $value) {
    echo $name . ' has a value of ' . $value.PHP_EOL;
    $calc = $value + 5;
    echo 'ADDED 5 - gives ' . $calc . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Result

```
2_of hearts has a value of 2
ADDED 5 - gives 7
3_of_hearts has a value of 3
ADDED 5 - gives 8
king_of_hearts has a value of 10
ADDED 5 - gives 15
```

Then you just do your calculation with the `$value` variable

Comment: When I do this, the $name and $value both show up as the value, making it unable to echo the card.

Comment: See new sample code, I added a dummy calculation using the `$value`

Comment: I noticed when I take all the '=> number' away, it does echo the card name, but as soon as I put => back it only echoes the number, in both $key and $value.

Comment: I have run this code, It does exactly what the result shows. You had better edit you question and post the real code you are using and I will see if I can see an error

Answer (score 0):

using this syntax of `foreach` lets you get access to the keys of the array

```
$cards = array("2_of hearts" => 2, "3_of_hearts" => 3, "king_of_hearts" => 10);
foreach($cards as $key=> $value){
    $key = explode("_",$key);
    $cardname = $key[count($key)-1];
    //echo $key[0] . " of " $cardname . "<br>";
    echo $value . " of " $cardname . "<br>"; // edit after comments
}
```

NOTE: this is off-course if you sure your keys are always has the pattern `#_of_cardname`

Comment: Whats wrong with using the value in `$value` and making life nice and easy

Comment: @RiggsFolly Nothing, he can use the `$value` off course. I just wanted him to extract the card name alone

Comment: @RiggsFolly In fact using `$value` is much more reliable, since the pattern can't ever be trusted, but as I said , I just wanted to extract the card name. off course  using `$value` is better than using `$key[0]`